# Beautiful Soup Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying for some time to find the bug in my code, I have already looked in related topics but could not find my mistake nor fix it, some help would be appreciated.

```
title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
price = soup.find(id="price_inside_buybox").get_text()
print(price.get_text())enter code here


File "price.py", line 18, in check_price
title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: Can u link to the html page also on which line is the error

Answer (score 0):

That means that there was nothing found with `id='productTitle'` and `.find()` method returned `None`. Check variable before extracting text